# How to setup Jprofiler in UnderTow

Tags: jprofiler, undertow

To do monitoring on the java application I'm planning to have jProfiler installed on the UnderTow where the applications are hosted.
Can anyone give me the setup instructions to install on the host where the Jprofiler needs to be installed and the related changes that I need to make on my client machine.

Answer (score 0):

To profile any Java application invoke

Session->Integration Wizards->New Remote Integration

and follow the steps on the wizard.